# Windows Features can't enable Hyper-V - Error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, vt-x

So it won't let me enable Hyper-V Platform, I could enable Hyper-V Management Tools though. I get the following message on Windows Features.

> Windows couldn't complete the requested changes.
>
> The parameter is incorrect.
>
> Error code: 0x80070057

---

Windows 10 Build (14393.447)

Processor: i7 860

VT-x is enabled in BIOS, VT-d is disabled.

Things I've tried:

- DISM
- Clean boot
- Disabled my antivirus

This is my `CBS.log` with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`:

```
2016-11-18 03:54:16, Error                 CSI    000000a7@2016/11/18:01:54:16.877 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\deltastore.cpp(2879): Error STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER originated in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::RecursivelyRegenerateComponentPayload expression: Parameter check failed
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-11-18 03:54:18, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 03:54:18, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-18 03:54:18, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-18 03:54:18, Info                  CBS    Not able to add poqexec.log to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000a8 (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #385989# from CFileInstaller::DoComponentOperation(...)[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000a9 (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #385988# from CFileInstaller::ProcessComponentChange(...)[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000aa (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #385987# from PrimitiveInstaller::CCoordinator::ProcessChange(Change (null) -> 10.0.14393.206 for Microsoft-Windows-Containers-ServerDefinition, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35})[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Info                  CSI    000000ab SMI Primitive Installer [done]

2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000ac (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #299374# from CCSDirectTransaction::PerformChangeAnalysis(...)[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000ad (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #299373# from CCSDirectTransaction::PrepareForCommit(...)[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000ae (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #299372# from CCSDirectTransaction::ExamineTransaction(...)[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000af (F) STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER #299371# from CCSDirectTransaction_IRtlTransaction::ExamineTransaction(...)[gle=0xd000000d]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000b0 (F) E_INVALIDARG #291959# from Windows::COM::CPendingTransaction::IStorePendingTransaction_Analyze(...)[gle=0x80070057]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000b1 (F) E_INVALIDARG #279081# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_Commit(Flags = 47, pSink = NULL, disp = 0, coldpatching = FALSE)[gle=0x80070057]
2016-11-18 03:54:21, Error                 CSI    000000b2 (F) E_INVALIDARG #279080# 13625036 us from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction_ICSITransaction::Commit(flags = 0x0000002f, pSink = NULL, disp = 0)
```

Rest of the CBS: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzySlw-8jB2ZVGl0Q2xxcmhlalE

Comment: clean winsxs folder with disk cleanup (WindowsUpdate cleanup), reboot and try again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Tried that, no luck though. I didn't even have Windows Update Cleanup in there.

Comment: hm, strange that Windows uses the older  10.0.14393.**206**. repair Windows: https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/, activate Hyper-V and now install the latest update rollup.